# Select a color using the number in openGL

Tags: opengl, colors

You know glColor3f(), which contains red green and blue values. I'm developing a simple program that should allow you to select a color so I'm not sure how to set up a set of RGB color values to make a callback. For example,

```
int red = (1,0,0);
glColor3f(red);
```

Obviously, this has an error so I've tried some other ways to make it work like
    int[] red = {1,0,0};
It still didn't work. Can you give me suggestions?

Update #1:
I made another program for just test. The first code line should be a global state.

```
GLfloat color[3] = {1,0,0};
```

then color should be changed by rand() in the following:

```
int r1 = rand() % 100;
if(r1 < 50)
    color = {0,1,0};
else
    color = {0,0,1};

glColor3fv(color);
```

Comment: I updated my answer to respect your question update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Learn the proper syntax of C, because this

```
int red = (1,0,0);
```

is not valid C. (C does not know a tuple type). Also types matter.

Well you could use a GLfloat array and pass it to `glColor3fv` (if you want to use integers you must use `glColor3i[v]`.

```
GLfloat const red[3] = {1,0,0};
glColor3fv(red);
```

But that's not very useful, because you normally do not want to artificially limit a user's choices. Just present them with a color selection widget, which returns you the individual color values, usually in a `struct` and pass that to OpenGL

```
struct color {
    enum {Color_sRGB, Color_HSV, Color_Lab, /* other color spaces */} type;
    union {
        struct { GLfloat r,g,b};
        struct { GLfloat h,s,v};
        struct { GLfloat l,a,b};
        /* other color spaces */
    };
};

/* defined somewhere else, converts a color to RGB color space */
void to_rgb(GLfloat rgb[3], color const *c);

void SetColor(color const *c) 
{
    GLfloat rgb[3];
    to_rgb(rgb, c);
    glColor3fv(rgb);
}
```

#### Update due to comment

To randomly select from a set of colors use this:

```
GLfloat const green[] = {0.f, 1.f, 0.f};
GLfloat const blue[]  = {0.f, 0.f, 1.f};
```

In C arrays have the interesting property, that their R-value is effectively a pointer to their first element. Hence for all practical means, wherever an array goes as argument, you can as well use a pointer.

```
GLfloat const *color; /* a pointer, not an array */
int r1 = rand() % 100;
if(r1 < 50)
    color = green;
else
    color = blue;

glColor3fv(color);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Color spaces are not important, but I still have one problem after I modified the program. Have a look at my code.

Firstly, I put a global state 'GLfloat color[3] = {0,0,0};' then I put a switch statement that allows you to select a color,

      'if (pointInRect(pt0, colorRED))
   color = setColor(red);'

So this should call to
'glColor3fv(color);'

 But the setColor has an error line. I'm trying to figure this out now.

Comment: @Shuvo0o: Again you're struggling with basic C syntax. C doesn't allow curly brace assignments to arrays for other things like initialization. You'll have to assign each element separately. However there's a much nicer solution.

Comment: Thank you, but there are errors in your code; 'color' inside the if-statement.

Comment: @Shuvo0o: Actually the solution would have been to add another const. Always remember: There can't be to few const.